# What is Azure Data Explorer? A Datalake? A datawarehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

As the title says, I'm confused about the role Azure Data Explorer has in the Azure data ecosystem. The documentation states that it's an analytics tool, but technically it ingests data from different sources such as kafka, spark and go on.

Is it some kind of enhanced datawarehouse?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

> **"For our own troubleshooting needs we wanted to run ad-hoc queries on
> the massive telemetry data stream produced by our service. Finding no
> suitable solution, we decided to create one"**
>
> **- Ziv Caspi Architect, Azure Data Explorer -**

Once we established the need, we can discuss the implementation.

Here are some key features:

- The service is distributed and can be easily scaled out (or in) which makes it good fit for big data (big as you need).
- The data is ingested into the service in batch/stream and stored in a propriety format.
- The data is stored in tables (columns & rows).
  Columns' data types include *bool*, *int*, *long*, *real*, *decimal*, *datetime* & *timespan* as well as native support for JSON (the *dynamic* data type).
- Everything is indexed, including free text that is tokenized and indexed with Full-text search index, which mean we can find rows with specific tokens in sub-seconds - seconds.
- The data is stored in a columnar format which makes it great for aggregations on large volumes.
- ADX has its own highly intuitive query language, KQL (Kusto Query Language), which supports numerous analytical features including distributed joins.
- ADX has native support for time-series with a lot of built-in functionality around it (forecast, anomaly detection etc.).
- Since the service was created to handle telemetry and telemetry does not change over time, the service was created as append only (inserts) + built-in support for data retention.
  Later on, soft & hard deletes were added.
  As of today, updates are not supported.

Here is some additional reading:

- [Ziv Caspi: Azure Data Explorer Technology 101](https://azure.microsoft.com/id-id/blog/azure-data-explorer-technology-101/)
- [Brian Harry: Introducing Application Insights Analytics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/introducing-application-analytics/)
- [Uri Barash: Azure Announcements: Azure Data Explorer](https://24,%202018)